# Implementing 3D graphics using only mathematical formulas?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I saw these amazing little programs(7kb,64kb) with stuning graphics.
I was wondering what technologies they used to implement these ?
OpenGL + Assembly ?

Here are the the videos :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfuierUvx1A&feature=related

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scSsxrMVXh8

Heaven 7 binary :

http://www.scene.org/file.php?file=/parties/2000/mekkasymposium00/in64/h7-final.zip&fileinfo

Conspiracy Binary :

http://conspiracy.hu/release/64k/chaos_theory/

All the textures animations , meshes are generated from mathematical formulas ?

Otherwise how can they be stored  in 7kb and 64kb binaries ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the art of the [demoscene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demoscene). Most of the meshes and textures and all other assets are made by [procedural graphics](http://in4k.northerndragons.ca/index.php?title=Procedural_Graphics_-_an_introduction).

The point where most demosceners meet themselves is [pouet.net](http://pouet.net/), there you can learn a lot or ask any question. As in other competitions, most sources and techniques are treasured by team (demoscene groups), but some tuts might be found like the [Ińigo Quilez's strawberry site](http://www.iquilezles.org/www/index.htm) and [DisplayHack blog](http://www.displayhack.org/).

The 64kB or nowadays more common 4kB demos are compressed by [kkrunchy](http://www.farbrausch.de/~fg/kkrunchy/) and [Crinkler](http://www.crinkler.net/) tools. These are amazing piece of software, which is full of applied statistics and awesome knowledge of C/Cpp/ASM generated executables.

You might find mode information about demoscene in this particular [Demoscene docs videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/demoscenedoc).